# Hide column in jQuery dataTables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I want to hide a column in `jQuery DataTables` that contains **Geo Zone** in its `th`. This is what I am doing :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        if(geo_zone_on_off==0){
            var _index=$("#datatable_ajax .heading th:contains(GeoZone)").index();
            var oTable=$("#datatable_ajax").DataTable();
            if(_index != -1){
                 oTable.column(_index).visible(false);
     }
        }
    });
```

The dataTable is loaded but the column does not get hidden. 
Before doing this I tried to hide it when the table was rendered and it worked fine. What I did then was:

```
 "initComplete": function(settings, json) {
                       if(geo_zone_on_off==0){
                        var _index=$("th.sorting:contains(GeoZone),th.no-sort:contains(GeoZone)").index();

                           if(_index != -1){
                             grid.getDataTable().column(_index).visible(false);
                           }
                       }
                       },
```

But it had a problem that it displayed the hidden columns when the table was loading. In order to avoid that issue I used the solution mentioned first. But it is not working although I am getting the index right. It does not give any error.

Comment: Not working is such a general way of describing an error, can you express yourself more clearly?

Comment: @Icepickle how should I elaborate it ? The column is not getting hidden thats all, though I have datatable object, column index and I am using them all right what more should I explain?

Comment: Do you ever intend to show that column? if not why drawing it at all?

Comment: I intend to. If `geo_zone_on_off ` is set to `1` I intend to display it. @bluehipy

Comment: Well, you mentioned that in the second construct the column was visible during dataloading, while for the first one you don't mention anything, except that it is not working, then my question was is the table not updating, or something similar :)

Comment: Datatable is loaded but the column does not gets hidden. I have edited the question @Icepickle

Comment: `preInit` is also not working. I want to avoid the problem of column being displayed when the table is loading.

Comment: As a side note, would `geo_zone_on_off` set to 1 mean it is not shown (as it is off?)

Comment: `geo_zone_on_off`  set to 1 means it will be displayed and 0 means it will be not. @Icepickle

Comment: Then based on that flag draw the column or not but don t play with hide/show.

Comment: Are you sure you are retrieving the correct `_index`? It is a bit hard to say based on the code available. Any chance you could make an MVCE? Also, did you try finding the header using the [`.columns( column-selector )`](https://datatables.net/reference/type/column-selector) instead of trying to find something that might not exist yet, or might be prone to changes? And for the keyword `geo_zone_on_off` I find the name semantically a bit double, I would probably either use `on` or `off` and then I could use a boolean flag, with `on_off` I might choose for string values `on` or `off` instead

Comment: looking for something like this https://jsfiddle.net/77j322k1/

Comment: Are you sure this: `oTable.column(_index).visible(false)` is the right way to do it? Did you try `oTable.column(_index).visible = false` ?

Comment: I am getting the right `_index` for sure as I have checked it in `console.log()` @Icepickle

Comment: @user5014677 I have done what was in documentation. And I have tried your way too and it doesn't work either

Comment: I would say then it is time to produce an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as this discussion with minimalistic code will bring us nowhere. There simply isn't enough code to decide what is wrong

Answer (score 2):

It dont have to be so complicated. Simply give the column a `name`. And why not set the `visible` status upon initialization? :

```js
columnDefs: [
  { targets: <index>, name: 'geozone', visible: geo_zone_on_off == 1 }
]
```

Then, later on, you can change the visibility by refer to the columns name :

```js
table.column('geozone:name').visible(false);
```

or

```js
table.column('geozone:name').visible( geo_zone_on_off == 1 );
```

Look at column selectors -> **https://datatables.net/reference/type/column-selector**

Comment: the problem is that the hidden column gets displayed when the datatable is loading. @davidkonrad

Comment: @Anonymous, not if you set `visible: false` in `columnDefs` or `columns`.

Answer (score 1):

Get Datatable object

```
var table = $('#table').DataTable();
```

Get column target to alter visibility

```
var target = //Get target of column to hide for eg for third column target = 2
var column = table.column( target );
```

Alter visibility

```
column.visible( false );
```

[DataTable Documentation](https://datatables.net/examples/api/show_hide.html)

Answer (score 0):

You want to hide a column which contains Geo Zone in th.

Try something like this

```
$('table').DataTable();
    $('button').on('click',function(){
        $('th').each(function(i,e){
        if($(this).text()=='No') {
         $(this).hide();
         $('tr').each(function(){
          $(this).find('td').each(function(index,element){
            if(index==i) {
              $(this).hide();
            }
          });
         });
        }
      });
    });
```

See the [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/77j322k1)